# Svn Externals Check-out Of Bzr Repo?

Tags: bazaar, svn-externals

Is it possible to check-out a Bzr repo via Svn externals using an Svn client?

If Bzr is being served over Web-DAV (it is in my case) it seems like it should be possible, unless Svn needs all the ".svn" folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bzr-svn plugin to push the bzr branch into you svn repository, then you can use that as an external.

Comment: That seems like the best solution for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. Cause Bzr is working different than subversion and the SVN client does not know how to handle a bzr repository.